# Node async stream piping

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream

I have this code working in Node 0.10, but it prints nothing in 0.8

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request('http://www.google.com:80', function(res) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.pipe(process.stdout);
    }, 0);
});
req.end();
```

After some guessing I found workaround:

```
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request('http://www.google.com:80', function(res) {
    res.pause();
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.resume();
        res.pipe(process.stdout);
    }, 0);
});
req.end();
```

But [documentation](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.24/docs/api/) says, that pause is advisory and this is confuses me. Why should I pause stream, which is not connected anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[0.10 revamped the Streams API](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/) and added the following change in behavior:

> **WARNING**: If you never add a `'data'` event handler, or call `resume()`, then it'll sit in a paused state forever and never emit `'end'`.

So, in 0.10, the stream will wait for a valid listener, like a `pipe`, or a forced `resume` without an explicit `pause`.

Steams in 0.8 and older, on the other hand, will start sending `'data'` immediately unless instructed to `pause`. And, in this case, that creates a race condition between the timeout and the stream -- the stream may run in part or even to completion before the timeout expires.

Comment: I think the old style (pre 0.10) streams should NOT have been called streams but something else. I think that's been the source of so much confusion for folks who have a certain expectation of what a stream API should look like coming from other languages.

Comment: @UstamanSangat A "*stream*" is just sequential data transmitted over time; and they certainly were that. What API that deserves is an entirely different matter of debate. But, expecting that one language's features will be matched exactly in another isn't typically a safe bet.

Comment: well... but apparently they gave in and realized that in 0.10 ;-)